# Alchemy api eth_getProof returns a wrong storage slot

Tags: json-rpc, mainnet, alchemy, goerli

I encountered a issue that eth_getProof returns wrong storage key and proof. This is a bash script which could reproduce the issue. And after some tests, I found increasing the interval between thoes requests will be helpful to reduce the number of the appearance of the issue.

```
API_KEY="Your Alchemy Api Key"
# response0_0 and response0_1 have same parameters, while response1_0 has a different parameter.
# Api eth_getProof should return two different result for response0_1 and response1_0, but it didn't in fact.
response0_0=$(curl https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/$API_KEY -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getProof","params":["0x449337bbe404cae0ba82f3451661af7481f37aac",["0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"],"0x7af32e"],"id":1}' 2>/dev/null)
response0_1=$(curl https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/$API_KEY -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getProof","params":["0x449337bbe404cae0ba82f3451661af7481f37aac",["0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"],"0x7af32e"],"id":1}' 2>/dev/null)
response1_0=$(curl https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/$API_KEY -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getProof","params":["0x449337bbe404cae0ba82f3451661af7481f37aac",["0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"],"0x7af32e"],"id":1}' 2>/dev/null)

if [[ "$response1_0" == "$response0_1" ]]; then
  echo "reponse1_0 should not equal to response0_1"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use the eth_getProof method from the Ethereum JSON-RPC API to retrieve storage proofs for a contract on the Goerli Ethereum testnet. The eth_getProof method returns a Merkle proof that can be used to verify the inclusion of a key-value pair in the contract's storage.

The issue you're encountering is that the eth_getProof method is returning the same result for two different requests with different storage keys. This is likely a bug in the implementation of the eth_getProof method on the Goerli Ethereum testnet.

To resolve this issue, you could try using a different Ethereum testnet or a different JSON-RPC API endpoint that provides the eth_getProof method. Alternatively, you could try using a different method from the Ethereum JSON-RPC API to retrieve storage proofs for your contract, such as eth_storageAt.

It's also worth noting that storage proofs are not supported on all Ethereum networks and may not be available on all JSON-RPC API endpoints. If you're unable to find a suitable solution for your use case, you may need to consider using a different approach for verifying the inclusion of key-value pairs in a contract's storage.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. This issue is so weird that I think other people may encounter likewise.